# Javascript How to contatenate two array elements if certain condition meets

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I'm working on a javascript function can solve basic algebra. (ex. x +5 +x +2 = 11).  I split the string where the equals sign is. Everything is printed into the console to test.

```
> [x +5 +x +2]
  11
```

Aft I split that, I split it again (the array with the variable and I get

```
> ["x", "+5", "+x", "+2"]
  11
```

Now I need to somehow concatenate the to variable part of the array. I was going to use .join() but that would join the whole array, whereas I just want to concatenate the elements in the array with a variable in it. This is what I need:

```
> ["x+x", "+5", "+2"]
  11
```

`array.join()` would return "x+5+x+2"

Comment: How are you going to do multiplication when it's mixed with addition?

Comment: Once I combine the like terms, ('x+x'), I'm going to take the opposite sign, (+ become -, * become /, etc) and move that array element next to the 11 (just like a real algebraic problem. eg. x + 3 * 4 = 11 would eventually become x = 11 - 3 / 4, then i'll use eval() to compute the right side of the equals sign.

Comment: Actually, I just computed that on paper, that doesn't give the correct answer, so before i move the terms over, I'll need to use eval() on terms without the variable first, then move that answer over then call eval() again

Comment: What if one side of the equation is e.g. x + 3 + x * 4? You cannot just move the variable around at will.

Comment: x * 4 is equivalent to 4x. x is equivalent to 1x, when those like terms are added, it becomes 5x. So the example you gave becomes 5x + 3 I'm taking baby steps as this is my first real program I'm writing. I'll add that  part of the code in when needed.

Comment: That implies another processing step (x * 4 => 4x) that you have not mentioned earlier. Anyway, I 'm not sure how much you are aiming to achieve exactly.

Comment: What is the exact input format? Is it always a 1-st order polynomial?

Comment: No, it's based on user input but I have a function that after I split where the equals sign is, It re-orders the array so that the first element is where the polynomial is.